Flutter: create home screen widget from app
I'm using this method:
Future<void> _requestToPinWidget() async {
    final isRequestPinSupported =
        await HomeWidget.isRequestPinWidgetSupported();
    if (isRequestPinSupported == true) {
      await HomeWidget.requestPinWidget(
        androidName: 'HomeScreenWidgetProvider',
        qualifiedAndroidName:
            'com.example.porftolio_investments.HomeScreenWidgetProvider',
      );
    }
  }

The first time, it asks for permissions correctly, but nothing happens after accepting or the next time I click the button.
If I specify a different androidName, it fails. Since I use Flutter, I'm not sure how to test this further. I added a try/catch in this method, and it works "fine", so I assume the problem comes from the native part.
The AndroidManifest.xml seems correct:
<receiver 
            android:name="HomeScreenWidgetProvider" 
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data 
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <!-- home screen widget -->
        <!-- HomeWidget background receiver -->
        <receiver 
            android:name="es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetBackgroundReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="es.antonborri.home_widget.action.BACKGROUND" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- HomeWidget background service -->
        <service
            android:name="es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetBackgroundService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:exported="true" />

The Flutter package is this one: https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget

After making some space in my home screen, the widget appears correctly
